# экспорт с таблицы на сайте на базе SQL в excel

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

При экспорте с таблицы на excel в ячейках где типа значений 10.123 экспортируются пустыми, а 10.000 уже как 10.

> Из-за чего может быть?

//Экспорт в ексель
protected void btExportXlsx_NotVisible_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
ds = (DataSet)Session[guid + "DataSet"];
DataTable dt_arxiv = (DataTable)Session[guid + "dt_arxiv"];

```
    string okpo = Session[guid + "okpo"].ToString();

    if (okpo != "")
    {
        //Excel.Application xlApp;
        //Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
        //Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        //xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        //xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

        Workbook workbook = new Workbook();

        DataTable dt_f_orm = frm_form.Copy();
        DataColumn[] keys = new DataColumn[3];
        keys[0] = dt_f_orm.Columns["razdel"];
        keys[1] = dt_f_orm.Columns["gr_st"];
        keys[2] = dt_f_orm.Columns["id"];
        dt_f_orm.PrimaryKey = keys;

        DataTable dtRz = dt_f_orm.Select("gr_st = 0", "ORD ASC").CopyToDataTable();

        //Информация
        workbook.Worksheets.Add().Name = "Информация";
        Worksheet xlWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets["Информация"];

        Range er = xlWorkSheet.Range["A1:A100"];
        er.Style.Alignment.WrapText = true;
        er.Font.Bold = true;
        er.Alignment.Horizontal = SpreadsheetHorizontalAlignment.Left;
        er.Alignment.Vertical = SpreadsheetVerticalAlignment.Center;
        er.Font.Size = 12;
        er.ColumnWidth = 500;
        er.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";

        er = xlWorkSheet.Range["A4:A4"];
        er.RowHeight = 200;

        er = xlWorkSheet.Range["B1:B100"];
        er.Style.Alignment.WrapText = true;
        er.Alignment.Horizontal = SpreadsheetHorizontalAlignment.Left;
        er.Alignment.Vertical = SpreadsheetVerticalAlignment.Center;
        er.Font.Size = 12;
        er.Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
        er.ColumnWidth = 2000;

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[0, 0].Value = "Год";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[0, 1].Value = Session[guid + "god"].ToString();

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 0].Value = "Период";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1].Value = lbl_mes.Text.ToString().Replace("Период: ", "");

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 0].Value = "";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1].Value = "";

        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 0].Value = "Наименование";
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1].Value = dt_arxiv.Select(list_pok[0][0].ToString() + " = '" + okpo + "'")[0]["name"].ToString();

        for (int i = 0; i < dt_bokovik.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 4, 0].Value = dt_bokovik.Rows[i]["name"].ToString();
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 4, 1].Value = dt_arxiv.Select(list_pok[0][0].ToString() + " = '" + okpo + "'")[0][dt_bokovik.Rows[i]["graph"].ToString()].ToString();
        }

        for (int r = 0; r < dtRz.Rows.Count; r++)
        {
            DataTable dtGR = dt_f_orm.Select("razdel = " + dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString() + " and gr_st = 2").CopyToDataTable();

            string sheet_name = ((dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString() + ". " + dtRz.Rows[r]["name"].ToString()).Length > 30 ? (dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString() + ". " + dtRz.Rows[r]["name"].ToString()).Substring(0, 25) + "..." : dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString() + ". " + dtRz.Rows[r]["name"].ToString());
            workbook.Worksheets.Add().Name = sheet_name;
            xlWorkSheet = workbook.Worksheets[sheet_name];

            xlWorkSheet.DefaultColumnWidth = 20;              

            er = xlWorkSheet.Range["A2"];
            er.ColumnWidth = 1500;
            er.RowHeight = 350;

            er = xlWorkSheet.Range["B2"];
            er.ColumnWidth = 300;
            er.RowHeight = 100;

            DataTable dtGR_col = frm_form.Select("razdel = " + dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString() + " and gr_st in (2,20)", "ord").CopyToDataTable();
            int j = 0;

            max_row_span = 0;
            js_array = ""; index_row = 0;
            foreach (DataRow gr in dtGR_col.Rows)
            {
                if (gr["KOD_PARENT"].ToString() == "")
                {
                    GridViewBandColumn band = gvTable_addColumn(dtGR_col, gr, Session[guid + "idf"].ToString(), r, "", 0);
                    MaxRowSpan(0, band);
                }
            }

            er = xlWorkSheet.Range.FromLTRB(0, 0, dtGR.Rows.Count + 1, max_row_span);
            er.Style.Alignment.WrapText = true;
            er.Font.Bold = true;
            er.Style.Alignment.Horizontal = SpreadsheetHorizontalAlignment.Center;
            er.Style.Alignment.Vertical = SpreadsheetVerticalAlignment.Center;
            er.ColumnWidth = 500;

            dt_range = new DataTable();
            dt_range.Columns.Add("x1", typeof(int));
            dt_range.Columns.Add("y1", typeof(int));
            dt_range.Columns.Add("x2", typeof(int));
            dt_range.Columns.Add("y2", typeof(int));
            dt_range.Columns.Add("value", typeof(string));
            col_level = 0;

            js_array = ""; index_row = 0;
            foreach (DataRow gr in dtGR_col.Rows)
            {
                if (gr["KOD_PARENT"].ToString() == "")
                {
                    GridViewBandColumn band = gvTable_addColumn(dtGR_col, gr, Session[guid + "idf"].ToString(), r, "", 0);
                    SetRangeDt(0, band);
                }
            }

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt_range.Rows)
            {
                er = xlWorkSheet.Range.FromLTRB(Convert.ToInt32(dr["x1"]), Convert.ToInt32(dr["y1"]), Convert.ToInt32(dr["x2"]), Convert.ToInt32(dr["y2"]));
                er.Merge();
                er.Value = dr["value"].ToString();
                er.FillColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
                er.Borders.SetAllBorders(Color.Black, BorderLineStyle.Thin);

                if (Convert.ToInt32(dr["x1"]) == 0 && Convert.ToInt32(dr["y1"]) == 0)
                    er.ColumnWidth = 1500;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 2; j <= ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    string column_name = "";
                    if (ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Columns[j].Caption == "name")
                    {
                        column_name = "А";
                        (xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2] as Range).Alignment.Horizontal = SpreadsheetHorizontalAlignment.Left;
                    }
                    else if (ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Columns[j].Caption == "kod")
                    {
                        column_name = "Б";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        column_name = ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Columns[j].Caption;

                        (xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2] as Range).Alignment.Horizontal = SpreadsheetHorizontalAlignment.Right;
                    }

                    string frmt = frm_cell.Select("kod_gr = '" + column_name + "' and razdel = '" + dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"] + "' and kod_st = '0'")[0]["frmt"].ToString();
                    if (ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i]["kod"].ToString() != "")
                    {
                        if (frm_cell.Select("kod_gr = '" + column_name + "' and razdel = '" + dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"] + "' and kod_st = '" + ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i]["kod"].ToString() + "'").Length > 0)
                            frmt = frm_cell.Select("kod_gr = '" + column_name + "' and razdel = '" + dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"] + "' and kod_st = '" + ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i]["kod"].ToString() + "'")[0]["frmt"].ToString();
                    }

                    if (frmt.Substring(0, 1) == "N")
                    {
                        // if (ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i][j].ToString().Replace("," , ".") != "")
                        //{
                        //  double value = Convert.ToDouble(ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i][j].ToString().Replace("," , ".").Trim());
                        // xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2].Value = value;
                        // }
                        if (double.TryParse(ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i][j].ToString().Trim(), out doubleValue))
                        {
                            xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2].Value = doubleValue;
                        }
                        else xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2].Value = null;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (column_name == "Б")
                        {
                            if (ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i][j].ToString().Replace(".", ",") != "")
                            {
                                xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2].Value = ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i][j].ToString();
                            }
                            else xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2].Value = null;
                        }
                        else xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2].Value = ds.Tables[dtRz.Rows[r]["razdel"].ToString()].Rows[i][j].ToString().Replace("&nbsp;", " ").Replace("</b>", "").Replace("<b>", "");
                    }

                    (xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2] as Range).Font.Name = "Times New Roman";
                    (xlWorkSheet.Cells[max_row_span + 1 + i, j - 2] as Range).Font.Size = 12;
                }
            }
        }

        workbook.Worksheets.RemoveAt(0);
        workbook.Worksheets.ActiveWorksheet = workbook.Worksheets[0];

        string fileName = okpo + ".xls";
        fileName = fileName.Replace(" ", "");

        workbook.SaveDocument(Server.MapPath(@"~\UploadControl\" + fileName), DocumentFormat.Xls);

        UploadingUtils.RemoveFileWithDelay(fileName, Server.MapPath(@"~\UploadControl\" + fileName), 5);

        HttpResponse Response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.ContentType = "xls";
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(@"~\UploadControl\" + fileName));
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}

int max_row_span = 0;
void MaxRowSpan(int row_span, GridViewBandColumn band)
{
    if (band.Columns.Count > 0)
    {
        row_span++;
        if (row_span > max_row_span)
            max_row_span = row_span;

        for (int i = 0; i < band.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (band.Columns[i].Columns.Count > 0)
                MaxRowSpan(row_span, (GridViewBandColumn)band.Columns[i]);
        }
    }
}

DataTable dt_range = new DataTable();
int col_level = 0;
int max_col_in_band = 0;
private IFormatProvider value;
private double doubleValue;

void SetRangeDt(int level, GridViewBandColumn band)
{
    if (band.Columns.Count > 0)
    {
        max_col_in_band = 0;
        getMaxColInBand(band);

        DataRow dr = dt_range.NewRow();
        dr["x1"] = col_level;
        dr["y1"] = level;
        dr["x2"] = col_level + max_col_in_band - 1;
        dr["y2"] = level;
        dr["value"] = band.Caption;
        dt_range.Rows.Add(dr);

        for (int i = 0; i < band.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (band.Columns[i].Columns.Count > 0)
                SetRangeDt(level + 1, (GridViewBandColumn)band.Columns[i]);
            else
            {
                dr = dt_range.NewRow();
                dr["x1"] = col_level;
                dr["y1"] = level + 1;
                dr["x2"] = col_level;
                dr["y2"] = max_row_span;
                dr["value"] = band.Columns[i].Caption;
                dt_range.Rows.Add(dr);

                col_level++;
            }
        }
    }
}

void getMaxColInBand(GridViewBandColumn band)
{
    if (band.Columns.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < band.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            if (band.Columns[i].Columns.Count > 0)
                getMaxColInBand((GridViewBandColumn)band.Columns[i]);
            else max_col_in_band++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Может из-за формата ячеек в Excel? Но лучше код показать и какие-то выдержки. Так можно только догадываться)

Comment: @xxramm ищу запрос который компилирует таблицу. напишу как найду если сам там уже не разберусь

Comment: @xxramm в xml норм выгружает, нашел из код выгрузки екселя из .cs

Comment: Какие ячейки? Или range ячеек?

Comment: Ну или примерно где в коде запись проблемной ячейки?